# Yamaha FZ 16 loses smoothness too soon

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha

I have a 2008 model Yamaha FZ. Lately, I have observed that the first week after a service, the motorbike is super smooth with good pickup. But after that it loses its smoothness and becomes dull.... You dont feel like the bike is smooth, it lags power... This happens after every service - 1 week smooth ride, then it deteriorates... 
This is a new phenomenon that has started happening lately, like 1 year...

Any guesses why this might happen? and how can it be avoided?

Comment: Smoothness is difficult to measure because it is subjective. Are you talking about vibration levels? Acceleration at full throttle? Power?

Comment: @DucatiKiller - FZ16 , a ~150 cc carbureted sibling . - http://www.yamaha-motor-india.com/product/fz16/specs.html

Comment: I'm wondering if its chain adjustment related, could be that its set correctly at the service and never adjusted between? that would certainly account for a lumpy ride.